# Mechanism of using sets as keys to map

Tags: c++, collections, reference

I have this code which I do not understand why it works:

```
map<set<int>,int> states;
set<int> s1 = {5,1,3}, s2 = {1,5,3};    
states[s1] = 42;
printf("%d", states[s2]); // 42
```

The output is 42, so the values of the states key are used for comparison somehow. How is this possible? I'd expect this not to work as in the similar example:

```
map<const char*,int> states;
char s1[]="foo", s2[]="foo";
states[s1] = 42;
printf("%d",states[s2]); // not 42
```

Here the address of the char pointer is used as the key, not the value of the memory where it points, right? Please explain what's the difference between these two samples.

Edit: I've just found something about [comparison object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/key_comp/) which explains a lot. But how is the comparison object created for sets? I can't see how it could be the default less object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were up to something with the comparison object.

One of the template parameters for a C++ [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) defines what acts as the comparison predicate, by default [`std::less<Key>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/), in this case `std::less<set<int>>`.

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/):

> The map object uses this expression to determine both the order the elements follow in the container and whether two element keys are equivalent (by comparing them reflexively: they are equivalent if !comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)). No two elements in a map container can have equivalent keys.

`std::less`:

> Binary function object class whose call returns whether the its first argument compares less than the second (as returned by operator `<`).
>   `std::set::key_comp`:
>   By default, this is a less object, which returns the same as `operator<`.

Now, [what does the less-than operator do?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/operators/):

> The less-than comparison (`operator<`) behaves as if using algorithm `lexicographical_compare`, which compares the elements sequentially using `operator<` in a reciprocal manner (i.e., checking both `a<b` and `b<a`) and stopping at the first occurrence.

Or from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbbhakzd.aspx):

> The comparison between set objects is based on a pairwise comparison of their elements. The less-than relationship between two objects is based on a comparison of the first pair of unequal elements.

So, since both sets are equivalent, because `set`s are ordered by key, using either as key refers to the same entry in the map.

But the second example uses a pointer as key, so the two equivalent values aren't equal as far as the map goes because the `operator<` in this case isn't defined in any special way, it's just a comparison between addresses. If you had used a `std::string` as key, they would have matched, though (because they do have their own `operator<`).

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons for this behavior:

- Sets are kept sorted as you input values, so s1 and s2 actually look the same if u print it out.
- Sets have overloaded operators so that s1 == s2 compares the contents instead
- the second example with *char explicitly put the pointer (address) as the key
- declaring the static string gives u different addresses for two instances of "foo"

  - if you put s2 = s1 instead instead you should get the same behavior

Comment: It doesn't compare the contents, it looks like the comparison object is used instead, see my edit.

Comment: @JanTuroň it does compare the contents, albeit indirectly

Comment: Ah, looking at the mechanism of less object used as the default comparison object, you are right: surprisingly to me, the comparison is O(n) if the key is std::set.

Answer (score 1):

looking at the documentation on cppreference.com:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

so if you don't supply your own custom comparison function, it orders the elements by the `<` operator, and:

```
operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=(std::set)...
Compares the contents of lhs and rhs
lexicographically. The comparison is
performed by a function equivalent to 
std::lexicographical_compare.
```

so when you call `<` on two sets it compares their sorted elements lexicographically.  your two sets, when sorted, are exactly the same.

Comment: Exactly what I later found also at cplusplus.com. Thanks for providing the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
cout << (s1 == s2);
```

You get an output of `1`. I don't know how sets in C++ work; I don't even know what they are. I do know that the `==` comparison operator does not return whether not the values of the sets are in the same order. Likely, it returns whether or not the sets contain the same values, regardless of order.

Edit: Yeah, the sets are sorted. So when you create them, they get sorted, which means they become the same thing. Use a `std::vector` or a `std::array`

Edit #2: They do become equal. Let me create an analogy.

```
int v1 = 4 + 1;
int v2 = 1 + 4;
```

Now obviously, v1 and v2 would be the same value. Sets are no different; once created, the contents are sorted, and when you compare using the `==` operator, which is how partially how `std::map` identifies mapped elements, it returns "yes, they are equal". That is why your code works how it works.

Comment: They surely don't become the same thing: if you add a value to some set, the other set is not affected. I understand the logic, but I still don't know the mechanism behind.

Comment: Misunderstanding. Equal is not "the same thing": v1==v2, but &v1!=&v2. The point is elsewhere, see the accepted answer. Anyway, thanks for effort.